# onResume Method in Fragment is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application I am using navigation drawer to move from one fragment to another.

If I move from about_us fragment to another then if I again comeback to same the activity is not getting resumed, instead the application is getting closed unfortunately.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code, pls tell me the solution to fix this.

```
public class AboutUsFragment extends Fragment {

public AboutUsFragment(){}

private GoogleMap gmap;

static final double latitude = 33.12615;
static final double longitude = 80.21932;

TextView aboutUs;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);

    initilizeMap();

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    View aboutUs = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.about_us_content_view);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

        //To enable compass
        gmap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        //To locate the school - Creating Marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("School Location");

        // adding marker
        gmap.addMarker(marker);

        //We assigned latitude and longitude in Coordinate
        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        CameraUpdate schoolLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 5);
        gmap.animateCamera(schoolLocation);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(coordinate)         // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
        .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
        .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
        .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
        .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void initilizeMap()
{
    if (gmap == null) {
        gmap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (gmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
}
```

And my about_us.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/map"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about_us_heading_View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/about_us"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/about_us_content_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/abouts_us_content"
            android:paddingTop="55dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

As I am completely new to Fragment. Someone pls tell me a noob way to fix it. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: add your fragment to the backstack

Comment: before adding it to fragment transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add fragment to backstack before committing fragmnetTransaction

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: As I am new to android development. I don't understand this fragment transaction. Can u provide me any link?

Comment: before comitting add to backstack. check http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-sliding-navigation-drawer-example.html

Comment: I added, but its showing error only. I think I am not properly adding the above code which u gave

Comment: follow the tutorial step by step. And if you are getting error please post your logcat error.

Comment: Can I mail u the project? this is what the errors I am getting http://s28.postimg.org/r9leftucd/Capture.jpg

Comment: can you post your AboutUsFragment xml?

Comment: I posted it in my question. Kindly check it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Fragment with mapFragment in layout crashes when you resume cause for a fragment onCreateView is called every time you visit it every time.
Try to make your rootView static like below,

public static View mRootView;
    public static boolean mOnRangeChange= false;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(mRootView==null){
            mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        }else{
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mRootView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(mRootView);
        }
        map_layout = (FrameLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.map_layout);
        mcategory = (Button) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.contact_categories);
        mSharedpreferenceUtility = SharedpreferenceUtility.getInstance(getActivity());
        mcategory.setOnClickListener(this);
        try {
            initializeMap(mRootView);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mRootView;
    }
```